# TSQL: Insert/Update with multiple tables/scope_identity()

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have two tabs on my front end collecting information for Addresses and Users. Currently, my stored procedures are called on the final submit button. My Addresses table has an ID (primary key), Line1, and Line2 column. My Users table has an ID (primary key) FirstName, LastName and AddressID column (which should map to the ID column in the addresses table). My address insert proc looks like this:

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[Addresses_Insert]
@Line1 nvarchar(50),
@Line2 nvarchar (50), = null
@ID = INT output
As
BEGIN
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Addresses]
           (                  
                [Line1],
                [Line2]
            )
     VALUES
           (@Line1, @Line2)

    SET    @Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()


END
```

My Users update looks like this:

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[Users_Update]
     @Id int
    ,@FirstName nvarchar(50) = null
    ,@LastName nvarchar(50) = null
    ,@AddressId INT = null

AS
BEGIN
UPDATE dbo.Users

SET
     [FirstName] = @FirstName
    ,[LastName] = @LastName
    ,[AddressId] = @AddressId --not sure about this

WHERE Id = @Id
```

I need to get the scope_identity() from the address stored procedure into the AddressID column for my Users table, but I'm not sure how to make that work.

Answer (score 0):

When you add your parameters in your code, set the @Id parameter as an output parameter and check the parameter value after your procedure executes:

```
      SqlParameter x = new SqlParameter();
      x.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
```

or you can just return the value from your @Id parameter like this:

```
     SET    @Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
     Return @Id
```